# REGEX to print every alternate word in a sentence

Tags: php, regex

Suppose i have a string:

```
$s= "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

I want to use php regex functions to retrieve every alternate word from the sentence. Like for the above sentence, the output should be:

```
The brown jumps the dog
```

Can anyone help me with the REGEX for this?

Comment: Sounds like a kinky brown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace every two words by the first one. So, replace

```
(\w+) \w+
```

by `$1`:

```
preg_replace('/(\w+) \w+/', "$1", 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
```

Quick test:

```
php -r 'echo preg_replace("/(\w+) \w+/", "$1", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");'
The brown jumps the dog
```

If you want the second, fourth, etc. words retained, then you can adapt the regex to

```
\w+ (\w+)
```

which will put the second word in a capture group. However. This will retain the very last word, even when the number of words is odd:

```
php -r "echo preg_replace('/\\w+ (\\w+)/', '\\1', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'),\"\\n\";"
quick fox over lazy dog
```

See that stray »dog« at the end? To solve that you need to remove the very last word if there isn't one following it:

```
\w+(?: (\w+))?
```

Demo:

```
php -r "echo preg_replace('/\\w+(?: (\\w+))?/', '\\1', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'),\"\\n\";"
quick fox over lazy
```

The `(?:...)` part is a so-called non-capturing group. It will group parts of the regex without capturing its contents for backreferences. This is here mainly so you can still replace by `$1` and not `$2`.

Comment: But this is an implementation in powershell. I dont know anything about it. could you please explain the working principle of your REGEX formula?

Comment: Good idea. In PHP: `$result = preg_replace('/(\w+) \w+/', '\1', $subject);`

Comment: one more doubt. what is the \1 for? and how can i modify this program to print the non matching words. I mean the output should be just the invert of the current one. hope you understand.

Comment: Coding-Freak: It should look the same in PHP with `preg_replace`. It's just that PowerShell is quite handy for quickly testing something and showing others that it works.

Comment: `$result = preg_replace('/\w+ (\w+)/', '\1', $subject);` I modified the code provided by Tim Pietzcker and this code now prints the other words that were deleted previously.

Comment: Coding-Freak: Note the issue with an odd number of words, I outlined in the answer.

Comment: Thank you sir Joey. You are a mastermind. Could you do me a favor? Please contact me on GTALK.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want to capture the matches in an array:

```
preg_match_all('/(?|(\w+) \w+|(\w+)$)/', $s, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

And to grab the opposite positions:

```
preg_match_all('/\w+ (\w+)/', $s, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```